# How to solve kernel panic issue

Tags: linux, debian, operating-systems, kernel-panic

I have a Debian OS upgraded from to 2.6 to 3.4 in my PC. All of a sudden some basic commands like `ls` and `sudo` were not working (by mistake I deleted some files in the root folder). I was getting a error like `bash- /usr/bin no such directory`. I restarted my PC after which it displays "kernel panic". How to resolve this issue.

Edit 1: I was deleting files from /mnt/sdc1 folder.something went wrong all of a sudden.

Comment: Probably, given the total lack of information as to what you deleted, the simplest thing is to re-install the OS. You should use a live distro to backup your own data on /home/yourname, then reinstall.

Comment: Yes, deleting files in the root folder is usually a bad idea. If you can't back up your data from the system itself (which seems likely), boot from a LiveCD or something.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae:What is "live distro"?

Comment: D'oh! I didn't notice @MariusMatutiae had already mentioned using a live distro. It means something like a LiveCD, a rescue disk. Something you can boot when the OS on your hard drive won't boot.

Comment: A live distro is a Linux distro mounted either on a USB stick, or on a CD/DVD. They are usually produced to install the system on a pc, but often offer the choice of **not** installing, and using the live stick as a repair medium. Ubuntu makes a very good one, even for beginners. Just make sure that, when you are presented with: **Install Ubuntu** and **Try it without installing it**, you choose **Try it without installing**. Then copy the contents of your pc's /home directory to an external disk, something like a USB hard disk. Then you are ready to re-install.